# My VB form size and executed form size differ? How do i fix this problem?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

i created a form in visual studio with a width of 89 but when i execute the form, the form width is more than 89. Can anyone show me how i can resolve this? below is my VB code when the form is loaded.

Its a specific problem.

```
Private Sub Show_form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim show_form As show_form = Me

    Dim y As Integer = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height -show_form.Height
    Dim x As Integer = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - show_form.Width

    show_form.TopMost = True
    show_form.Location = New Point(x, y)

End Sub
```

My form width in design mode:

[image]

My form width when loaded.

[image]

I expect the form width in design mode to be same as in play mode.

Comment: Can you show us how the properties of the form are set?

Comment: i solved it on my own by adding this line of code New System.Drawing.Size(width, height)